# How to filter records in yii by records not in the table

Tags: php, yii

I have a table for invoice tracking between office departments. Once I register invoice a transaction is inserted into the table. I forward to logistics office and anothet transaction is inserted. In the table I have currentLocationId, nextlocationId, timein, timeout, action.
When I forward the invoice I dont update the previous record of registring the invoice but i need once i have forwarded the invoice It gets out of the queue. Bearing in mind that the initial transaction of registering is intact, not updated, how can i filter in YII model to fetch only records which have been registered but not yet forwarded?

Below is my model search.

```
 public function showPending($id)
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.


        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->with = array('invoices');
                $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->compare('InvoiceTrackingID',$this->InvoiceTrackingID);
        $criteria->compare('invoices.TrackingCode',$this->TrackingCode);
        $criteria->compare('TimeInStamp',$this->TimeInStamp,true);
        $criteria->compare('TimeOutStamp',$this->TimeOutStamp,true);
        $criteria->compare('Comments',$this->Comments,true);
        $criteria->compare('CurrentUnitLocationID',$this->CurrentUnitLocationID = $id); // see if the invoice is in your unit location
                $criteria->compare('UserID',$this->UserID);
        $criteria->compare('TrackingActionID',$this->TrackingActionID = 2);  // fetch only invoices whose action was to forward to display

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I need to see your tables , but anyway  you need to add condition to your criteria 
and will be like that :

```
$criteria->addCondition(" your condition here ");
```

Also you can use complex condition like this : 
for example

```
$criteria->addCondition(" ticket_id not in (select ticket_id  from table where coulmn=$section_id ) ");
```

*note : add condition statement in first line  like :

```
public function showPending($id)
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.


        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->addCondition(" your condition here ");
                $criteria->with = array('invoices');
                $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->compare('InvoiceTrackingID',$this->InvoiceTrackingID);
        $criteria->compare('invoices.TrackingCode',$this->TrackingCode);
        $criteria->compare('TimeInStamp',$this->TimeInStamp,true);
        $criteria->compare('TimeOutStamp',$this->TimeOutStamp,true);
        $criteria->compare('Comments',$this->Comments,true);
        $criteria->compare('CurrentUnitLocationID',$this->CurrentUnitLocationID = $id); // see if the invoice is in your unit location
                $criteria->compare('UserID',$this->UserID);
        $criteria->compare('TrackingActionID',$this->TrackingActionID = 2);  // fetch only invoices whose action was to forward to display

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```